# AWS Lambda function (node.js) can't find installed ffmpeg

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

thanx in advance!

My lambda function shall transcode videos.
I install the function via a Docker image and ECR.

Inside the lambda function ffmpeg cant be executed/ found.

**Dockerfile**: As base image I use the AWS node base image. I install ffmpeg on that image and execute it successfully after installation "RUN ffmpeg -version" (works) I then copy the ffmpeg to /usr/local/bin.

Inside the **lambda function** I try to run the same command "ffmpeg -version" via exec() but there I get "command not found".

the command "pwd" returns the path "/var/task"

Any idea?

Dockerfile (excerpt):

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18
```

```
RUN yum install -y tar gzip xz
```

```
RUN curl -O https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xzRUN tar xvf ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xzRUN ls ffmpeg-6.1-amd64-staticRUN cp ffmpeg-6.1-amd64-static/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/RUN cp ffmpeg-6.1-amd64-static/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/RUN rm -rf ffmpeg-6.1-amd64-static
```

```
RUN ffmpeg -version
```

```
COPY --from=lambda-builder /apps/lambda-video-processor ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

```
CMD ["index.handler"]
```

inside **lambda function**:

```
exec("ffmpeg -version", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
if (error)
    {console.log(error: ${error.message})
    return
}
if (stderr)
    {console.log(stderr: ${stderr})
    return
}
console.log(stdout ffmpeg version: ${stdout})
})
```

Comment: You can have much simpler setup. No docker needed. You can just download a suitable ffmpeg binary (suitable for lambda) and pack it together with your lambda code or as a lambda layer.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks!

I want to have the lambda function during the dev process automatically updated and deployed via GitHub actions on merge, this is why I went this Docker way. Works well so far, just not ffmpeg.

Would it be possible to stay with the Docker workflow (without ffmpeg installation) and then add "your" ffmpeg lambda layer on top? As a static layer so to say?